# What is mean by channel inversion in wireless communication

Tags: wireless, transmitter, receiver, telecommunications

Regarding the title of the question, to my understanding, Channel Inversion means that "The transmitter adapts its power to  maintain constant SIR at the receiver."

It is a technique used for adaptive power control.

However, I am not sure if my understanding is correct.

Comment: Channel Inversion is a complex subset of various algorithms used for optimal communications between multi-input, multi-output (MIMO) transceivers. Cell phone towers would be one example. Much too complex to elaborate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "The transmitter adapts its power to maintain constant SIR at the receiver."

When only one transmitter is involved, that might seem like a pointless thing to do.

When multiple different transmitters, perhaps at very different distances, are involved, it means that each transmitter arrives at the single receiver at the same power level, which optimises their signal to mutual interference ratio. Without this control, the nearest transmitter may swamp the weaker signals from the other more distant transmitters.

Comment: specifically, with a digital base station, you can get away with digitising everything with one ADC, as long as the levels are all similar. Otherwise you need lots more ADC resolution and linearity.

Comment: I am talking about uplink cellular transmission where multiple transmitters (interfering nodes to the main transmitter) are involved, especially at the cell edges